# Get Minimum bounds of 4 LatLon

Tags: javascript, geometry, bounds

I have 4 Lat Lon positions. They represent a (rotated) rectangular region. But due to some calculation errors, sometimes they are not proper rectangular.

I want to convert those into (rotated) rectangular regions.
See Image for more clarification

[image]

In the above image I want the lat lon of the corners of the rectangle drawn given 4 lat lon as shown on the left side.

I tried searching but couldn't find any solution. Most of the solutions did not take care of rotated rectangle case. 
How do I solve this problem ?

Note : Are there any libraries that does this, I am using JavaScript for implementation.
Note : I don't know if my question is more related to math.

Comment: Do you have your code that handles the rotation?

Comment: Actually I get the values from some API for which I don't have any code.

Comment: So are you looking to calculate a bounding box around the vertices you have, or something else?

Comment: I am looking to calculate the vertices of bounding box around the 4 points that I have. I want the vertices of the dotted rectangle that is shown in the image, given the 4 points that are shown on the left of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note : This is the particular solution that I used. It may not be perfect but it works.

Algorithm :

- Calculate the distance between 1, 3 and 1, 2 lat lon from the image. This would give you 2 distances.
- Find the coordinates along which the distance is greater. (In here lets consider the distance between 1 and 3 is greater.)
- Find the bearing between those considered coordinates
- Consider any coordinate as origin. (I choose coordinates of 3 as the origin for my case).
- Rotate all points 1,2,3,4 along the origin with rotation angle as bearing. Here the rotation makes the considered points (here 1 and 3) to be parallel to the x axis.
- Now you get 4 new coordinates. Find the minimum and maximum x and y from those 4 coordinates (consider them to be minX, minY, maxX, maxY).
- The (minX, minY) gives you the top left coordinates of the rectangle and (maxX, maxY) gives you the bottom right coordinates of the rectangle. Using this information you can find the other two coordinates.
- Now rotate these 4 new coordinates along the same origin but with rotation angle as -bearing. These are the vertices of the dotted rectangle in the image.

Note : This may not be perfect as I have not considered the earth radius and other complications associated with latitude, longitudes. But in my case the lat lon were pretty close to each other, and I wasn't interested in accuracy.

Hope some of us find it useful.